# dated reminders .net mvc web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api2, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Im building an **mvc5 & webapi 2 website** and am struggling with the concept of message queues and general bus.  Specifically, im experimenting with adding tasks and specifying a date for the due date for those tasks.  **I would like to send out a reminder to the users for said tasks a day before the task is due (without the user being logged in, so kind of like a background task)**.

**I have an email service configured** and works when a user makes a task. For example, user enters a task and JS function fires to a web api that structures the task and uses my email service to send the email.  But this is user input dependent and only works when the user first inputs a task.

My Stack - 
**- MVC5 ASP.NET(standard) & WebApi2
- SQL Server
- JS and AJAX
- AWS hosted**

**Some researching points me to the direction of SQS and SNS** and I kind of get the queuing system but i still don't see how the original message will get to the SNS Topic to then hit the queue.  Also, SQS queues have a lifetime for messages at 14 days max, this wont work for Tasks that are due months from current date. 
 So I cant just send a task over and have it sit there for longer than 14 days till delivery.  In the past when I wrote code with PHP we made cron jobs for our MySQL server tables to see if anything changed then act or output somewhere and wrote small applications to listen for changes and then email.  Not sure something like that exists for .NET or if SQS/SNS option is the best way.

Things I researched:

```
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/queues-and-notifications-now-best-friends/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UesxWuZMZqI
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/sns-apis-intro.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html
```

Comment: Sorry guys meant to say "Hi Stack Overflow!" guess that part got cut out :).    I appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've identified the Work Queue and the Work Consumer. You're missing the Work Producer. The web app is a producer but that requires user interaction (as you've recognized).

The simplest thing to do is write a (console) program that reads through your event store and generates work (current reminders) for the queue. Then you'd schedule that program to execute on a recurring cycle -- like a cron job. Windows has the Task Scheduler as well as cron-like services from other vendors.

You can get fancier and build a service out of your program so that it will run continuously.

Comment: ahh ok thanks @Jasen, yeah i figured as much, just hoped for something a little "easier" but dont we all!!  Thank you for your input, **marked**